# Find first three non- zero terms of the Taylor's series method of this question

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the solutions u(0.1) and u(0.2), of the initial value problem u' = x(1 − 2u² }u(0) = 1
Using the first three non- zero terms of the Taylor's series method and h=0.1

Comment: please response if anyone can do it

Comment: Welcome to math SE. You have a better chance of recieving help if you show us what you tried. Also, have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your equations.